# Можно ли выполнять таски в Celery по очереди?

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, celery

Всем привет! У меня есть две таски `download_and_send_youtube_video` и `clear_cache_youtube_video`. Код:

```
@celery.task
def clear_cache_youtube_video(video_path: Path):
    """Clear YouTube video from cache"""
    if os.path.exists(video_path):
        os.remove(video_path)


@celery.task
@inject
def download_and_send_youtube_video(
        chat_id: int,
        link: str,
        redis_client: Redis = Provide[WorkerContainer.redis_client]
Provide[WorkerContainer.assistant_grpc_client]  # Передаётся через dependency injector
):
    assistant_grpc_client = AssistantGrpcClient(ASSISTANT_GRPC_ADDR)

    try:
        yt = YouTube(link)
    except pytube.exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
        logger.info(f'{link}: video is unavailable')
        return

    if yt.length >= YT_MAX_VIDEO_LENGTH:
        logger.info(f'{link} video too long')
        return

    # forward message if it's existing in cache
    yt_cached_msg_id = f'youtube:{yt.video_id}'
    if redis_client.exists(yt_cached_msg_id):
        chat_message_id = redis_client.get(yt_cached_msg_id).decode()
        from_chat_id, message_id = map(int, chat_message_id.split(':'))
        req = ForwardMessagesRequest(
            from_chat_id=from_chat_id,
            chat_id=chat_id,
            disable_notification=True
        )
        req.message_ids.append(message_id)
        assistant_grpc_client.stub.forward_messages(req)
        return

    stream = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').get_highest_resolution()
    if stream is None:
        logger.warning(f'{link}: stream is not available')
        return

    out_filename = yt.video_id
    video_path = stream.download(YT_OUT_DIR, out_filename)

    caption = remove_hashtags(yt.title).strip()
    req = SendVideoRequest(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        video_path=video_path,
        caption=caption,
        disable_notification=True
    )
    result_msg = assistant_grpc_client.stub.send_video(req)

    video_ttl = timedelta(seconds=YT_VIDEO_TTL)
    # cache message id in Redis store
    redis_client.set(yt_cached_msg_id, f'{chat_id}:{result_msg.id}', video_ttl)

    release_date = datetime.now() + video_ttl
    clear_cache_youtube_video.apply_async((video_path,), eta=release_date)

...
```

```
@bot.on_message
async def handle_new_message(client: Client, link: str):
     await chat_id = client.get_chat_id();
     download_and_send_youtube_video.delay(chat_id, link)
```

`clear_cache_youtube_video` удаляет видео из кеша.

`download_and_send_youtube_video` вызывается, когда пользователь отправляет кому-нибудь сообщение.

Внутри `download_and_send_youtube_video`:

```
Есть ли видео в кеше? 
  Пересылаем сообщение из другого диалога.
Иначе:
  Скачиваем видео.
  Отправляем пользователю.
  Сохраняем на несколько минут в Redis информацию ключ: youtube_video_id, значение: "chat_id:message_id".
  Создаём таску clear_cache_youtube_video на удаление видео через 3 минуты.
```

Если запустить воркер со стандартным значением `concurrency = 8` и запустить одновременно (почти), например, три таски `download_and_send_youtube_video`, то видео будет скачиваться в трёх тасках и после загрузки создастся три таски `clear_cache_youtube_video` для удаление видео из кеша. Это плохо с точки зрения производительности, так как видео скачивается в пустую 3 раза и 3 раза удаляться.

В данному случае лучше исполнять таски `download_and_send_youtube_video` последовательно. Тогда в примере с 3-мя тасками видео будет скачиваться один раз, 2 раза пересылаться сообщение из чата со скачанным видео, 1 раз удалится видео из кеша. Это можно сделать, если установить `concurrency = 1`, но тогда все таски в Celery будут исполняться по очереди. Мне бы хотелось сделать так, чтобы только таски `download_and_send_youtube_video` исполнялись по очереди. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, как можно так сделать в Celery?

**Примечание:**
`download_and_send_youtube_video` исполняю в воркере для того, чтобы не стопить поток обработки сообщений (функция `handle_new_message`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтоб ограничить одновременное исполнение задач используйте [маршрутизацию](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/routing.html).

Создайте специальный маршрут для `download_and_send_youtube_video` так, чтоб все задачи `download_and_send_youtube_video`  попадали в отдельную очередь, которую будет обрабатывать только один процесс. Для этого в конфигурацию celery добавьте параметр `task_routes`:

```
task_routes = {'path.to.tasks.download_and_send_youtube_video': {'queue': 'downloads'}}
```

Теперь вам нужно запустить обработчики (celery worker) два раза, один для очереди по умолчанию (если не меняли названия то она называется `celery`) с нужной вам `concurrency`, и второй для очереди `downloads` с `concurrency=1`:

```
celery -A myproj worker -Q celery --concurrency=10
celery -A myproj worker -Q downloads --concurrency=1
```

Но конкретно для вашей задачи это не лучшее решение, так как будет заблокированно одновременное скачивание разных видео. Лучшее решение, это разделить задачу на две: отдельно задача на скачивание, отдельно - на посылку.

Задача на скачивание, должна записать в redis признак того, что она собирается скачивать такое то видео, проверив сначала, что этот признак не установлен. Если признак уже установлен, т.е. другая задача уже скачивает, то качать заново не нужно, нужно только сохранить информацию о том, кому нужно будет послать файл по окончанию скачивания. Опять же это можно сохранить в redis. После того, как файл скачался, нужно разослать его всем кому нужно.

Comment: Спасибо большое!